# The inno setup compiler is not running my C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, inno-setup

I tried in both C/C++ to ensure that I am not missing out on something. Even the simple hello world program is not running in there. The error message displayed says,

> name of the header file(s) I include" file not found.

I have entered the header file in both of the formats to double check its working;
`"stdio.h"` and `<stdio.h>`

But nothing seems to be working.
I even copied the examples that came along with its package, but the same error appeared there too.
How do I tackle this out?

Comment: Show the `include` code... don't just describe it. Your description can't show us if you missed a closing quote or correctly used the the "<>" brackets for system headers (i.e. `<stdio.h>` ).

Comment: What does Inno Setup compiler have to do with `stdio.h`? Your question makes little sense. Show us some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have a clear idea of what you are asking. Did you tag Inno Setup by mistake?

> I even copied the examples that came along with its package, but the same error appeared there too.

Inno setup doesn't come along with C++ examples.... It has only [PASCAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal) code in it. I am pretty sure that The package you mentioned **isn't Inno Setup**.

But if you really are trying to execute C++ code in Inno Setup, I think you have mistaken the word compiler. Languages mostly use their own compiler to compile their code.

You are trying to use Inno-setup compiler which compiles only **Object Pascal code** (Using [Rem Objects](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx)) which means that it can only compile code which adheres to [Object Pascal Standards](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Object_Pascal_Tutorial). You cannot compile **C/C++** code in an Inno Setup Compiler. You will need to use one of the compilers specified in this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.2B.2B_compilers). Moreover Inno Setup is a packaging application used to pack your application into a setup.exe and install it in a target(client) system. All the PASCAL code compiled in inno-setup perform actions related to this specific process.